# GET parameters from jQuery in PHP file not carrying over?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have some data in an ajax request that I am sending to a php file as an endpoint.

The code is the following:

```
// some calculations above here, but to keep things minimal assume they produce the following
totalBeforeTip = 38.43;
tipTotal = 5.77;
totalWithTip = 44.48;
saleCount = "3";
  console.log("List for the query String: " + totalBeforeTip 
                                        + "\n Tips: " + tipTotal 
                                        + " \n Totals+Tip: "+ totalWithTip
                                        + "\n Totals Sales: " + saleCount);

  // Send get to php with q-string

  $.ajax({
    url:"summary.php",
    type: "get",
    data:{
      TotalSales: saleCount, 
      TotalsNoTip:totalBeforeTip, 
      TotalTip: tipTotal, 
      TotalWithTip: totalWithTip
    },
    success: function(resp){
      console.log(resp);
      window.location.href = "summary.php";
    },
    error: function(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
```

And my php is the following:

```
<main>
    <?php
    $TotalSales = $_GET["TotalSales"];
    $TotalTips =  $_GET["TotalTip"];
    $TotalBeforeTip = $_GET["TotalsNoTip"];
    $TotalWithTip = $_GET["TotalWithTip"];
    ?>
 <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-6'>
                  <form> <!--Main form for user interaction-->
                    <div class='form-group bigger-group'>
                      <label>Sales: </label>
                      <input readonly value="<?php echo $TotalSales  ?>" />
                    </div>
                      <div class='form-group'>
                          <label>Totals Before Tips:</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class='form-group'>
                          <label>Total Tip Cost:</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class='form-group'>
                          <label>Total Cost with Tip:</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class=col-md-6>
                    <h1>Cost ($)</h1>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <input readonly value="<?php echo $TotalBeforeTip ?>"/>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <input readonly value="<?php echo $TotalTips ?>"/>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <input readonly value="<?php echo $TotalWithTip ?>"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</main>
```

When I redirect my fields are blank but in the response in the console log they are filled. I tried to do a page redirect to the `resp` it doesn't do anything. After poking at it quite a bit I got it to work by adding the following line to `success: function(resp){....}`.

```
window.location = "summary.php?TotalSales="+saleCount+"&TotalsNoTip="+totalBeforeTip+"&TotalTip="+tipTotal+"&TotalWithTip="+totalWithTip;
```

For some reason this works, and the fields in the php have the proper data but I don't see how? Or why it is that the data I passed in with the `.ajax` method just evaporated?

I've been struggling with this for two days and it works but I don't understand why at all. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: _"For some reason this works"_ - only because it makes a second request after your faulty AJAX request ... so this isn't a real solution. When are you making this AJAX request, where are the variables (`saleCount` etc.) that you are populating your data object with coming from? Have you logged their values to console right before this AJAX call?
 Please go check how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Why on earth are you ajax-ing to summary.php and then doing a full redirect to it immediately afterwards? It makes no sense. The whole point of ajax is to remove the need for page refreshes/redirects/postbacks. You're also making 2 HTTP requests when one would do. Why not just redirect directly to summary.php, with those values on the querystring, if that's what you need? Or, do an ajax call to it, get the response and then do something with that response within the current page (which is the entire purpose of ajax)?

Comment: And of course your values are blank when you do the redirect - you only sent them to the ajax request. You didn't supply them when you do the redirect. They are two separate HTTP requests to that URL. Each request is treated individually by the server. What you sent last time you requested that same URL is totally irrelevant. If you want to send values to the server on one request, and then use those values later when another request to the server (not necessarily the same URL) is made, then you need to persist those values somewhere - common solutions  include sessions, database, or cookies.

Comment: I guess this is more of a general (and somewhat opinionated?) piece of advice but, people don't generally capitalize the first letter of their variable names. That's usually only done in for class names iirc. It makes variables slightly easier to read, and easier to type if you don't capitalize the first letter. What you are doing is totally valid however, and you of course can continue to do it if you wish.

Comment: Woah lots of feedback, firstly @CBroe I left those values out since those are part of a way bigger calculation that is not part of my question. The values that they produce are intended and work fine. It's the ajax that I'm lost on. But I included some sample data from one of my test runs. Which should make a more complete answer

Comment: @ADyson I agree it didn't make sense to me, this was part of an assignment and it was one of those `to the wire` things that just so happened to work. I know it's two requests but the first ajax thing wasn't working for me. Should I have just done a redirect with the queryString instead of using ajax? Since the goal was to navigate the user to the php page?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton thanks, I am brand new to AJAX and PHP but this part of the assignment really had me stumped. From what it sounds like PHP naming conventions are similar to javascript

Comment: @KazRodgers yep. Your answer is correct on this.

Comment: @KazRodgers You could take a look at [this article I found regarding conventions](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/9-confusing-naming-conventions-for-beginners--net-15584)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with the combination of all the feedback I've received and some more googling I've learned that AJAX is for `ACTION` not `CONTENT` and the core purpose of AJAX is to perform background processing without holding main flow on a page. Some good examples are :

- Loading new tweets on twitter
- Giving a notification if you have a new email in your inbox
- Validating form fields on blur

Since in my case I wanted to send the `totalBeforeTip, tipTotal, totalWithTip, saleCount` to my `summary.php` to load the content of the input fields based off that data. Using AJAX for it is a bad approach because this should be done in a synchronous process.

I used the following code to accomplish this outside of ajax

`window.location = "summary.php?TotalSales="+saleCount+"&TotalsNoTip="+totalBeforeTip+"&TotalTip="+tipTotal+"&TotalWithTip="+totalWithTip;`

All I needed was the queryString.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location = "summary.php?TotalSales="+saleCount+"&TotalsNoTip="+totalBeforeTip+"&TotalTip="+tipTotal+"&TotalWithTip="+totalWithTip;
```

You need to do like these because Ajax get the response on same page and from that page you will be send the response to another page and then you get the response using $_GET['variables'].